# How can I add information to a specific column and row in a listview?

Tags: vb.net, listview

**The short version:**

How can I add information to a specific column and row in a listview?

**The longer version:**

With some textboxes and buttons in another form I add items to my listview like this

```
        Dim li As ListViewItem

        li = Form1.ListView1.Items.Add("1")
        li.SubItems.Add(tbName1.Text)
        li.SubItems.Add(Form1.tbCount1.Text)
        li.SubItems.Add(tbType1.Text)
        li.SubItems.Add(Form1.tbStatus1.Text)

        Form1.ListView1.EndUpdate()
        Form1.ListView1.Refresh()
```

This is the output so far...

[image]

`Tbname1.text` (Column below *Channel*) and `tbtype1.text` (Column below *Type*) are specified in textboxes before i hit the button.

`Tbcount1.text` in form1 contains a number based on count of files within a folder. `TbStatus.text` is based on how many files there are. This count is hooked to another button (eventually a timer). This is why you'll notice Queue and Status is empty.

Now if I'd hit that button (or timer) - lets say `btnUpdate` before the settings in my other form, it would look like this

[image]

**Here comes the problem...**

I now want to update **only** the information under the column Queue (tbcount1.text) and Status (tbstatus.text) with `btnUpdate`

For example I have this counter

```
        If Form2.cbc1.Checked = True Then
        Try
            Dim fileTotal As Integer
            For Each item As String In lbChannel1.Items
                fileTotal += My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(item.ToString).Count
            Next
            tbCount1.Text = String.Format("{0}", fileTotal.ToString)
        Catch ex As Exception
            lbErrors.Items.Add(String.Concat("Error: ", ex.Message)) 'Error output
        End Try
        Dim tCount As Integer = 0
        'Til status
        If Val(tbCount1.Text) > 20 Then
            tbStatus1.Text = ("Many files")
        Else
            tbStatus1.Text = ("Good")
        End If
    End If
```

Which works perfectly. It gives me the number and word I want in the two textboxes, but at the moment I have to refresh the whole listview to get that count-output into the columns.

**I've tried...**

To add this under the `btnUpdate`...

```
        Dim str(4) As String
    Dim itm As ListViewItem

    str(0) = ""
    str(1) = ""
    str(2) = (tbCount1.Text)
    str(3) = ""
    str(4) = (tbStatus1.Text)

    itm = New ListViewItem(str)
    ListView1.Items.Add(itm)
```

Sadly, this jumps to a second row. See image below.

[image]

**So here is what I want in other words:** when `btnupdate` is pressed or a timer is at 100; update *specified row* - column 3 with `tbcount.text` and update *specified row* - column 5 with `tbstatus.text`. That wraps up my question.

I found some information on this in C#, but I need it in VB.net. I might be close or far away. Hopefully it was understandable anyways.

Comment: Consider using a DataGridView/DataGrid bound to a DataTable instead.

Comment: Thanks for your input. That might have been better indeed. However, when I took a look at it, I got the impression it is quite more difficult to tweak than a listview. I might be wrong though. Is it more friendly considering working with columns and rows this way?

Comment: ListView is designed to provide a Windows Explorer like interface to your data. The grids are designed to work with rows and columns of data. It all depends on the definition of "tweak" as to which would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily manipulate the listview items directly whenever you want.

If you have the item selected, that you want to change, you simply access it like this:

```
myListview.selecteditems(0).text = ""
myListview.selecteditems(0).subitems(1).text
myListview.selecteditems(0).subitems(2).text
myListview.selecteditems(0).subitems(3).text
```

You dont have to re-assign the whole listviewitem every time you change it, just change whatever needs changing...

If you do not have the item selected in the listview (row), you will have to step through the listviewitems collection until you find the item (row) you are looking for, and then manipulate whatever parts of it you need to.

```
For each item in mylistview.items
 if item.text = "whatoever"
  'this is my item....
  'manipulate it....
  item.text = "sdfdsf"
  item.subitems(1).text = "ddsfdsfdsa"
  'etc
 end if
next
```

Note: Subitems are (1) based, not 0...

Comment: Thank you!! This is pretty much what I was looking for. Tested a few things based on your answer and it now works like I want it to. The only thing I had to change because I'm not selecting an item as I update, I changed "selecteditems" to "items".